# Fabric API getting the color of a grass block

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

I recently started modding minecraft using the fabric api.

I want to get the **color of the grass block** the player is currently standing on. I found that in the Biome class there is a method called `getGrassColorAt(double x,double y)` **I managed to get it's data but it's an int. And I don't know how to use it**.

For instance by calling `getGrassColorAt(double x,double y)` in a plain biome I would get: -7226023, in a river biome I would get -7423631. In a desert it would be -4212907.

I know the color of a grass block is determined with a texture map called grass.png as I have read on [this](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tint#Grass_2) but i don't know how an int could help me using it.

NB: If getting the color is impossible I would like to at least get the name of the biome (I could not find a getName in the class)

And if anyone know where I can get a readable documentation can you link it please. (I'm currently using my IDE to know the different methods from a class)

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone on the fabric discord helped me.
So apparently the data vas encoded in the string I had to isolate the r g b values directly from the bits (or so I understood) here is the solution (j is the color as an int)

```
int r = j >> 16 & 255;
int g = j >> 8 & 255;
int b = j & 255;
```